# Are there any ways for a martial class to reduce an enemy's armor class?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class, martial

I recently had a player express interest in playing a martial character (d&d 5e) who could somehow reduce an enemy's AC. My understanding is that the flavor they were going for is based on things like Monster Hunter where a player can chop off parts of a monster to weaken their armor and set up for bigger hits. The only way I could think of to reduce AC was through the slow spell, which doesn't really fit the flavor that the player is going for. Anything I'm missing? Is there a martial class, subclass, or feat that would allow a player to reduce AC?

Comment: As the first answer asks: Are you looking for literal AC reduction only? Or anything that makes the target easier to hit (e.g. advantage)? Or anything that weakens the target on a hit in general?

Answer (score 4):

### Sort of but...

So dnd 5e has a long list of combat rules that cover the general ways to effectively reduce AC on a target (by improving the odds of hitting). Creating Advantage through stunning, restraining, or making an enemy prone is the most standard of standard ways to do this. Alternatively, you can create advantage through the Help action and just flavor it as exposing a weakness. These are your more standard options. However, if you want to go for true AC reduction then this is where the "but" comes in.

##### The Shieldbreaker

If you are so inclined you can have a player work to degrade or destroy shields/armor/weapons by attacking those items specifically. This is in the rules at large (items can have HP and AC) and can be modified from certain creatures (I believe in one of the adventures there's an NPC who's particularly adept at destroying the party's gear). So the player would swing at the defenses of any humanoid foe utilizing armor or shields. But...

##### One Size Doesn't Fit All

There are no rules for reducing armor in a martial class outright. As you've already stated there is only a select few spells period that reduce armor outright. Additionally, dragons don't rely on shields. So a marital class that's good at breaking objects won't be doing that a lot against any creature that doesn't rely on such defensive items.

In summary, there are ways to get martial classes that effectively reduce AC by granting advantage (which in theory improves the odds of hitting). But there is no way for them to actually reduce AC of creatures that don't boost their AC with shields and armor.